# Clojure Seesaw make menu of radio-menu items out of a list of files

Tags: list, user-interface, menu, clojure, seesaw

I have a list of files like so `("File1" "File2" "File3")`

I want to turn this into a of radio-menu-items
like this

```
 (menu :text "Lists" :items [(radio-menu-item :text "File 1")(radio-menu-item :text "File 2")(radio-menu-item :text "File 3")])
```

I have tried looping like this

```
(def Radios (for [ item '("File1" "File2" "File3")]  (radio-menu-item  :text item)))
```

but this does not work.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your use of a `for` expression looks correct, if I change the expression slightly so it returns the list it would run instead of running it we can verify this:

```
core>  (list 'menu :text "Lists" :items  
          (vec (for [ item '("File1" "File2" "File3")]   
                   (list 'radio-menu-item  :text item))))

(menu :text "Lists" :items [(radio-menu-item :text "File1") 
                            (radio-menu-item :text "File2") 
                            (radio-menu-item :text "File3")])
```

so the finished expression becomes:

```
core>  (menu :text "Lists" :items  
          (vec (for [ item '("File1" "File2" "File3")]   
                   (radio-menu-item  :text item))))
```

provided that `menu` and `radio-menu-item` resolve to the proper values.

Comment: Wow so simple and I could not get
Thanks :)

Comment: and the important thing here is that `for` is lazy so your original `def` didn't do anything. The `:items` property of `(menu)` will also force the sequence, so `vec` isn't actually necessary.